# ImportError: libOpenGL.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

When I am running my `python` program I am getting following error in my terminal.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./encryption.py", line 6, in <module>
    from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
ImportError: libOpenGL.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How to solve it?
The import statements in my program are

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import random
import re
import pyAesCrypt
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

run the following command, to install `libopengl0` library it required to run the code.

```
sudo apt install libopengl0 -y
```

Answer (score 13):

The problem is a [bug in PySide 6](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1547), which is apparently caused by a [bug in Qt 6](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-89754). Until that's fixed, you have to install OpenGL separately from installing PySide 6.

I installed it on Ubuntu 20.04 with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me when running Pytest + PySide6 in a python:3.9 Docker container.

Comment: This solved it for me on Fedora too `sudo dnf install freeglut freeglut-devel`

Comment: The command for Rocky linux/Centos: yum install freeglut freeglut-devel